# Should a LINQ projection be strongly typed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, projection, strong-typing

I have an aggregated data view in an MVC project which displays the totals per month broken down by audit status.  The controller code sets this up using a simple LINQ projection into an anonymous object like this:

```
From audits In db.Audits
Group By key = audits.DateCreated.Value.Month Into g = Group
Select New With {
    .Month = key,
    .Assigned = g.Sum(AuditsWithStatus(AuditStatus.Issued)),
    .Unassigned = g.Sum(AuditsWithStatus(AuditStatus.Pending)),
    .Closed = g.Sum(AuditsWithStatus(AuditStatus.Closed)),
    .Cancelled = g.Sum(AuditsWithStatus(AuditStatus.Cancelled))
}
```

I know this is one of the big advantages of LINQ (using anonymous types), but I don't like losing the strong typing in the view (ie @ModelType SomeStrongType).  Is there any general advice on this?  Articles, blogs, or other places that deal with the issue and when to use which?

Comment: anonymous types are generated at compile time.  they are still strongly typed from the perspective of the runtime - they just have compiler generated names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do anything with anonymous types outside of the scope of your method. You cannot return them to your view for example. In those cases you have to use a known type.

I use anonymous types when I am selecting data that I am then processing in another way. For example, selecting some bespoke data out of 1 source using Linq, and putting to put into another source.

If you are returning aggregate data such as an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TValue>>` and `TKey` and `TValue` are anonymous types (you can group by anonymous types if you want); then you would not want to create 2 classes for `TKey` and `TValue`, where `TKey` has an overridden `Equals` and `GetHashCode` so you can group by it. And then do nothing more than read some values from it and throw it away, never to be re-used.

**TLDR;** use them when there is no need to create a known type to store your results. If you need to pass your results to somewhere outside the scope of the method, then you will need a type.

Answer (score 0):

General advice is simple: always create dedicated viewmodel type for your views. In your case it would be pretty simple, containing exactly the properties you have in you anonymous class.

I understand that it seems like an unneeded overhead, but it'll make your code more readable and verifiable.